# Is property overloading possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, jsdoc

I know that I can overload functions, but is it possible to overload properties? I mainly want to do this so I can have seperate documentation for the type that gets passed to the property.

As seen here both are the same value but I want to have different JSDoc for when the value is of one type and JSDoc for when the value is of another type.

```js
interface Example {
  /** When a string is passed "x" will happen. */
  prop: string;
  /** When a number is passed "y" will add something. */
  prop: number;
}
```

When I try I get a Duplicate identifier error.

> Duplicate identifier 'prop'.

[image: Duplicate identifier]

Comment: Why not `prop: string | number`? You could just document both on the same prop. In your code, it's always going to be type `string | number` anyways.

Comment: Because then I can't use separate JSDoc for number and string, I have to add it all as one.

Comment: Ok, but how would you then *use* this interface? How would you tell TypeScript which to use?

Comment: Not sure... It can figure it out with methods/functions I would assume the same would be possible for properties

Comment: why not use a `type` with a union: https://tsplay.dev/WvGyQw

Comment: @TobiasS. JSDoc doesn't seem to work then... unless that is just in the online editor

Comment: @TobiasS. If you don't narrow it then it displays both docs concatenated which is really annoying: https://tsplay.dev/Wy6z2w - But I guess if they are going to be using doc comments like this ("When ...") it makes sense.

Comment: "Overload" isn't really what you mean here... if a function is overloaded, then its type is essentially an *intersection* of function types.  Something like `{(a: string): number; (b: number): string;}` is *both* `(a: string)=>number` *and* `(b: number)=>string`.  So "overloading" a property would mean that `prop` is *both* a `string` *and* a `number`, or `string & number`, which is impossible.  You seem to want something more like a *union* (as others have mentioned).  I guess unions don't give you the IntelliSense you want, but overloads are still not really the right term here.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't sure what something like this would be called.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Example = {
  /** When a string is passed "x" will happen. */
  prop: string;
} | {
  /** When a number is passed "y" will add something. */
  prop: number;
}
```

Well, this answer may not be perfect for *your use case*, but you didn't provide the use case (it would be based on the same concept anyways)